# Class in the attribute compartment of another class

Tags: object, attributes, uml, class-diagram

Is it possible to add a class as an attribute of another class?

If it is normal situation, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two (possibly three) ways of doing this:

1- using the attribute text.

2- using the association notation.

(3- both)

See this [image](http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/ch16_9780131489066/elementLinks/16fig03.jpg).

This is the [full article](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1398623&seqNum=5) by Craig Larman.

Answer (score 1):

This is absolutely normal. 
Response by @jurgenreza is comprehensive. 
Among the various options he shows, I'm one of the detractors of option 3 (because of redundancy).

Comment: Totally agree, that is why I wrote "possibly" three. No offense, but your answer is better off as a comment. Cheers.